# Issue when writing a python list to excel, list items are missing

Tags: python-3.x

Just recently started using Python, the version I have is 3.5

I'm using openpyxl to write a list to a single column on an excel sheet, nothing too complicated, here is the code:

```
import openpyxl
import random

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('testSave.xlsx')
target_sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Destination')

##create a list with random numbers
for i in range(1,20):
    container.append(random.randint(1,20))

for j in container:
    rowIn = container.index(i)
    target_sheet.cell(row = rowIn + 1, column = 1).value = container[rowIn]

wb.save('testSave.xlsx')
```

When I open the workbook several of the list items are missing, 10 in total, not sure what I'm doing wrong, been researching about this for a few days now without any luck, it is probably something silly, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`list.index()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) is not doing what you think it does - it returns the first index of the element value found in the list. Given that you can have duplicate elements in the list you will never get indexes of the repeated elements. If you want to enumerate your list, use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
import openpyxl
import random

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('testSave.xlsx')
target_sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Destination')

##create a list with random numbers
for i in range(1,20):
    container.append(random.randint(1,20))

for i, j in enumerate(container):
    target_sheet.cell(row = i + 1, column = 1).value = j

wb.save('testSave.xlsx')
```

Comment: thank you Zwer, much appreciated, no wonder it was driving me crazy.